Older versions of lxml and pandas on WIndows 10 in 2024
I've recently ran into an issue where I have to install an older (4.6.2) version of lxml to use an older version of pandas, however, when installing via pip install lxml==4.6.2, the wheel simply won't build due to missing libxml2.
Someone made a port of libxml2 to Windows, and the instructions essentially boil down to "you're already supposed to know how to install it" (thanks, very useful). Extracting binaries from bin of the linked library ports to a $PATH-included directory did nothing.
The commonly linked in older discussions on libxml2, lxml and various issues regarding its install storage of pre-build wheels, according to archive.org, either redirects to a github link where only modern versions are pre-built (e. g. 5.2.2 for lxml).
Using the aforementioned archive.org, I've been able to find the list of pre-built wheels and install the one I needed, but otherwise, is that it? Just rely on archive.org?

A more sustainable solution would be to build (or reuse) a Docker image with all the necessary libraries. That might be a bit more work upfront, though

The binaries from zlatkovic.com are 13 years old and completely outdated. Please don't use them.
